# How to send Unicode symbols using SQL Server Database Mail?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail, unicode

How can I send Unicode symbols using SQL Server Database Mail? My goal is to send a symbol on the subject of an email. Let's say that, for example, I want to send this  " Subject with symbol" on the subject. The symbol I want to use come from Segoe UI Emoji font.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `@subject = N'';`? I didn't follow this all the way through (I don't have a local system with database mail enabled) but the big thing that trips people up when dealing with Unicode characters is the simple `N` prefix. [See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEohf.png).

Comment: Thank to your suggestion is working now. I was sending the value to a store procedure with the N but I have the parameter with varchar  DECLARE "@Subject varchar(50)"  once I changed to DECLARE "@Subject nvarchar(50)"  works, Thanks!

Comment: What is that make this question "Too localized"?

Comment: I did not vote but a lot of people use that reason for minor typos and simple issues that won't help a lot of people. You want to use Unicode characters but you chose varchar, that's probably the last time you'll do that. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you always use `nvarchar` as the data type throughout the whole flow, and always prefix Unicode strings with `N`. There is a big difference:

> [image]